# Expose a variable outside of an if statement

Tags: ios, iphone, swift3

I'm trying to mess around with Swift code and I'm wondering what this piece of code does:

```
if let location = locations.first {
     var locVariable = location.coordinate
}
```

I know it gets the coordinate, but more simply. What does the statement mean?

Because when I try to do this:

```
if let location = locations.first {
     var locVariable = location.coordinate
}
print(locVariable)
```

the last line will produce an error saying "Use of unresolved identifier 'locVariable'"

Is there a way to make locVariable available globally and not just be available inside the if statement?

Sorry, newbie here. And would love to learn from you guys.

Comment: Swift statements: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH33-ID434

Comment: Hi. I know the basics of if statements. I'm just wondering why I can't use a variable that's inside the if statement to be used outside of it. Also, would like it to be explained in a more simplistic manner and relevant to the sample code as above.

Comment: I realize it's an essential concept in OOP and actually have a basic understanding of what scoping is (meaning you can't it the variable outside of where you declared it in). I was just hoping there's a practical way of explaining what this does as reading a book and having someone explain it in a practical way is way better. I learn better through examples. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use `guard` for this case:

```
guard let location = locations.first else { return }
var locVariable = location.coordinate
print(locVariable)
```

Comment: Thank you. Although it doesn't explain what my sample code does, it does give me an alternative to go around it.

Answer (score 2):

This is a small section plagiarised from 
https://andybargh.com/lifetime-scope-and-namespaces-in-swift/
please read the whole section.
I hope it helps give you a starter for understanding the concept of scope.

```
let three = 3 // global scope
print("Global Scope:")
print(three) // Legal as can see things in the same or enclosing scope.
func outerFunction() {
    print("OuterFunction Scope:")
    var two = 2 // scoped to the braces of the outerFunction
    print(two) // Legal as can see things in the same or enclosing scope.
    print(three) // Also legal as can see things in same or enclosing scope.
    if true {
        print("If Statement Scope:")
        var one = 1 // scoped to the braces of the `if` statement.
        print(one) // Legal as can see things in the same or enclosing scope.
        print(two) // Legal as can see things in same or enclosing scopes.
        print(three) // Also legal for the same reason.
    }
    // print(one) - Would cause an error. Variable `one` is no accessible from outer scope.
}
// print(two) - Would cause an error. Variable `two` is not accessible from outer scope.
```

Comment: Yeah. This one is pretty easy to understand because of the way it's structured. Thanks.